# Zend Framework htaccess Backend / Frontend

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, frontend, backend

In my current ZF project, I've two public access points (files) ready to handle & process coming requests, that's: index.php & admin.php

I need all URLs containing '/admin' to be routed to admin.php while any other URLs doesn't contain '/admin' to be routed to index.php

Knowing that default ZF htaccess contains the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

How this can be implemented?

Comment: I don't understand why you have to do such thing. You can simply have one entry point and, based on the url, add a new route that redirect to the right controller (or wharever you want).

Comment: This is a big project that contains too many modules for each Backend & Frontend, 'admin' can't be neither a single module nor scattered controllers inside every module. Both Backend & Fronend should be completely separated so every end can get benefit of the full modular features. And that's why I see that two access points are required. If you understand my circumstances & know a better solution, please don't hesitate to advice.

Comment: Well, if I understand well your needs, this can be still done using routes and a single entry point. Infact, you are always redirecting the user based on the url and so I see no difference in using routes or two entry points.

Comment: Something like this: http://wdvl.com/Authoring/PHP/Zend_Routes/Jason_Gilmore04282010.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to start by saying that I full heartedly agree with AurelioDeRosa. I do believe that routes will be a better choice. However that is your choice not mine and this .htaccess code should do the trick you want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*(admin).*$ admin.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Note however that this script will catch anything that contains admin so it might break your frontend. for example, if you want to list all your users with administrative rights the url *yoursite.com/users/listby/admin/* will redirect the request to admin.php, and so will urls like /administrator/ or /adminininini

Comment: Sorry, these rules not working! It is still routing all requests to index.php

Comment: Strange. For some reason the code didn't work with the slashes. I'm no expert in rewrite RegExp do I can't explain why, but I've corrected and tested the code and updated my answer above.